# How do I grab cells from excel and insert them into an outlook email?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm on VBA 7 and Excel 2010.

I'm trying to create a button that will automatically take cells C4:J15 from my spreadsheet and insert it in an email.  But no matter what combination I list for xmailbody (see code), the email is blank.  How do I get the values?  The formatting would be nice to copy as well, but that's not absolutely necessary

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xMailBody As String
On Error Resume Next
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
xMailBody = ActiveSheet.Range(F7).Value
          On Error Resume Next
With xOutMail
    .To = "test@test.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Schedule Request"
    .Body = xMailBody
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
MsgBox ("Your request has been submitted to your supervisor.  Please contact your supervisor if you do not receive a reply in the same business day")
End Sub
```

I want to be able to have a button in my excel spreadsheet that will insert values into an outlook email and automatically send.  This will be used for employees to email their scheduled hours every week.

Comment: `xBody` is a 2-d array of cell values - you will need to loop over that and format it to a string which can be assigned to the `Body` property.  You can't pass an array directly.

Comment: Thanks for commenting so early this Monday morning.  Can you help me more? This is my first time using VB so I'm a little dense.  Can you give me an example of possible code, or route me to a page on how to make a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ron de Bruin write really useful code in VBA on his website and had helped me to understand better interactions with Outlook. This one for exemple (just a copy paste, modified for taking your cell F7) might do the job. Do not forget to change the field To, CC, Subject etc:

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range("F7")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = No
End function
```

Comment: Do not forget the "End Function" at end, I've just edited it 1min ago

Comment: Thanks for your help